# how to call setBadgeValue method for tabbar item

Tags: ios

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

    [[[self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem]setBadgeValue:@"1"];
}
```

I use storyboard for UI and want to set notifications number for one of the tabbar items, but it seems that I do something wrong.

What is wrong with this code, why I don't see the notification in the tabbar item?

Thanks in advance.

ANSWER:

```
FROM APPDELEGATE:
     UITabBarController *tabController = self.window.rootViewController;
        UIViewController *requiredViewController = [tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
        UITabBarItem *item = requiredViewController.tabBarItem;
        [item setBadgeValue:@"1"];
```

Comment: the above method doesn't work, but as I understand I should see the notification.

Comment: @downvoters, please explain or make response. I am novice in ios and for me it seems not very evident - why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Although I didn't downvote this, I suspect that the reason for the downvote was the same reason for which I asked what the problem was. Your question should be more precise and more informative.

Comment: many thanks for your feedback,problem: what's wrong with the above code, why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is it all on one line?

Break it down into a few smaller steps, set a breakpoint on step one and walk through the code checking to see if what you expect is happening on each line.

```
UIViewController *rootController = self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBarController *tabController = rootController.tabBarController;
UIViewController *requiredViewController = [tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item = requiredViewController.tabBarItem;
[item setBadgeValue:@"1"];
```

I suspect that one of your properties is `nil` - this is usually the cause of 'why does my method fail without any warning or error` type bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence but don't accept my answer until you've proved it's helpful - I might be completely wrong!